# node_object_prepare causes profile page for non-admin users

Tags: nodes, 6

When I'm calling node_object_prepare in a module to create a user profile type node Drupal 6 kicks the user out unless they have admin permissions.

How can I make node_object_prepare run regardless of the users role?

thank you,
George

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by ripping the guts out of the node_object_prepare function, pasting it into the module and editing it appropriately so it served my purpose.